# Как можно перевести «сделано на коленке»?

Tags: переводы, идиомы, английский-язык

В значении «быстро, не затрачивая много времени и усилий; наспех».

Comment: A quick hack например, только это офтопик здесь.

Comment: @tum_, спасибо за вариант. Вроде, "вопросы, связанные с переводом, не запрещены...". Почему оффтопик?

Comment: А, ну и хорошо, если не запрещены... Наверное, путаю разные ресурсы - везде свой устав, свои правила.

Comment: На [соседнем ресурсе](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/18467/working-on-a-knee) не так давно обсуждалось, кстати.

Comment: "Если вы не знаете, как лучше построить переведенную фразу, напишите ее дословный перевод с языка-источника." — В [справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) идёт речь именно о переводе с иностранного на русский. А наоборот — эффективнее спрашивать носителей английского.

Comment: @oleedd, спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: @tum_, может, оформите как ответ?

Comment: 'A quick hack' совсем не то. Посмотрите тут: https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, спасибо за ссылку. Можете тоже оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Мультитране есть неплохие переводы "[на коленке](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5)". Из них вам больше всего подойдёт 'quick-and-dirty' (как прилагательное), правда, у него явно негативный оттенок — сделанный тяп-ляп. А на коленке у умельца может получиться и быстро, и довольно качественно порой. Варианты *using whatever was available, at bench scale, in one's garage, as a kitchen-table effort* больше подходят в смысле *самодельный, сделанный из подручных материалов.*